# android TextView: setting the background color dynamically doesn't work

Tags: android, textview

Setting the background color programatically of an android `TextView` doesn't seem to work.
I'm I missing something!

```
TextView et = new TextView(activity);
et.setText("350");
et.setBackgroundColor(R.color.white);
```

I also have this file (colors.xml) in my res/values folder

```
<resources>
        <color name="white">#ffffffff</color>
        <color name="black">#ff000000</color>
</resources>
```

[EDIT]: 
Also, setting the text color causes the TextView to disappear.

```
TextView c1 = new TextView(activity);
c1.setTextColor(R.color.solid_red);
c1.setText("My Text");
```

Answer (score 363, accepted):

Use `et.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);`

Comment: The android API is really something, why couldn't it throw an error?

Comment: Because it is not an error. setBackgroundColor() takes a color in numeric form (e.g., 0xFFFF0000 for red). R.color.white is also a number.

Comment: D'oh! This definitely could have been done better with enums rather than ubiquitous ints. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: They *could* be using different type signatures! One called ColorId and another called HexColor or something. Both are integers but they aren't the same *type*

Comment: Very strange. From documentation: 
The resource should refer to a **Drawable** object or 0 to remove the background.

Answer (score 77):

Try this:

```
TextView c1 = new TextView(activity);
c1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.solid_red));
c1.setText("My Text");
```

I agree that a color and a resource have the same type, but I also spend a few hours to find this solution.

Comment: I don't fully understand it right now (looking over api doc's) but it does work, so thank you!

Comment: Thanks, you have saved me a few hours! Now that I know the solution, it makes sense to me but I'm sure it would have taken me a few hours to figure this out on my own.

Comment: Thanks. Android API is really non-intuitive at times.

Answer (score 67):

To set red color:

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(0xfff00000);
```

Or

```
<color name="solid_red">#fff00000</color>

textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.solid_red);
```

Comment: To echo badMonkey's answer given this is the more popular answer, you MUST set the high order bits to non zero for the transparency. I get caught all the time by specifying the RGB without the A. To set the background to pure blue, use 0xff0000ff, not 0x0000ff or it won't work.

Comment: In the .xml the value of a <color> element works with only the classic 6 digits: #FF0000

Comment: @WeaponX: it works fine with transparent colors (in 8 digits).

Comment: @Weapn X The function takes an integer, 4 bytes. 6 hex digits is 3 bytes.

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar issue where I was creating a numeric color without considering the leading alpha channel.  ie.  `mytext.setTextColor(0xFF0000)` (thinking this would be red ).  While this is a red color it is also 100% transparent as `it = 0x00FF0000;`  The correct 100% opaque value is `0xFFFF0000` or `mytext.setTextcolor(0xFFFF0000)`.

Answer (score 14):

Just this 1 line of code changed the background programmatically

```
tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));
```

Answer (score 8):

Well I had situation when web service returned a color in hex format like "#CC2233" and I wanted to put this color on textView by using setBackGroundColor(), so I used android Color class to get int  value of hex string and passed it to mentioned function. Everything worked.
This is example:

```
String myHexColor = "#CC2233";
TextView myView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myView.setBackGroundColor(Color.pasrsehexString(myHexColor));
```

P.S. posted this answer because other solutions didn't work for me. I hope this will help someone:)

Answer (score 6):

here is in little detail,

if you are in activity use this

```
textview.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.yourcolor));
```

if you are in fragment use below code

```
textview.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(),R.color.yourcolor));
```

if you are in recyclerview adapter use below code

```
textview.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.yourcolor));

// use holder.textview if you are in onBindviewholder
//here context is passed from fragment
```

Answer (score 4):

```
tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.solid_red));
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps to do it correctly:

1. First of all, declare an instance of TextView in your MainActivity.java as follows:

   ```
   TextView mTextView;
   ```
2. Set some text DYNAMICALLY(if you want) as follows:

   ```
   mTextView.setText("some_text");
   ```
3. Now, to set the background color, you need to define your own color in the res->values->colors.xml file as follows:

   ```
   <resources>
       <color name="my_color">#000000</color>
   </resources>
   ```
4. You can now use "my_color" color in your java file to set the background dynamically as follows:

   ```
   mTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.my_color);
   ```

Answer (score 3):

`Color.parseHexColor("17ee27")` did not work for me, instead `Color.parseColor("17ee27")` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

two ways to do that:

1.create color in colors.xml file like:

```
<resources>
        <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

and use it int activity java class as:

```
et.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
```

2.

```
et.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                or
et.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to support all versions:
Try this:

```
myTextView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.mycolor));
```

Answer (score 1):

Jut use

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptername = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, your array list);
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting colors from resource follow this:

`textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ButtonColorRed));`

Here ButtonColorRed is color name in color resource

Answer (score 0):

If you try the above solutions and it still doesn't work, have a look at your TextView xml and make sure that you remove android:background (cuz it may overlap your et.setBackGroundColor(R.color.yourcolor)

Answer (score -11):

you can use `android:textColor= "` whatever text color u want to give" in xml file where your text view is declared.

Comment: Programatically... not xml