# How to set the main LinearLayout width to the maximum size w/o xml?

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to write application where I create layout in the code (without xml-layout file). In the xml file I could write:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

What should I write in the code?
I look for something like:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.set?????? (????) ;
```

Comment: Please read FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures regarding the signature.

Comment: Hi Sameera, I read. What do u mean?

Comment: I had to remove your signature from the post due to policy of the SO. I just gave you that policy link from FAQ. :)

Comment: Hi Sameera, I didn't know that I had one, so it's ok :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this out.

```
LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
l.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693744/340068) out as an example