# Android get color as string value

Tags: android, colors

If i defined a color in resources

```
<resources>
    <color name="someColor">#123456</color>
</resources>
```

it's possible to set color by its id, like

```
view.setTextColor(R.color.someColor);
```

Is it also possible to get color string value from colors.xml?

Something like

```
colorStr = getColor(R.color.someColor);
// -> colorStr = "#123456"
```

If yes, can anybody give an example?

Thank you

Answer (score 175, accepted):

This is your answer

```
colorStr=getResources().getString(R.color.someColor);
```

you will get

```
 colorStr = "#123456"
```

Comment: first, thank you. I did't thought to use getString for colors. It works, but instead of colorStr = "#123456" i'm getting "#ff123456", and this is not nice :(

Comment: of course, I can cut 'ff' out, but I try to solve my problem in other way

Comment: I wanted to use html tags, but i think I'll just use setTextColor(id)

Comment: No issue.Then what was the purpose of raise the question?

Comment: sorry, I wanted to make my life easier. And common. I've learn something new :)

Comment: and now i know, why did i want to use html-tags instead of setTextColor. The setTextColor didn't work. But i found solution for this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466788/android-textview-setting-the-background-color-dynamically-doesnt-work/2112933#2112933

Comment: A simple substring of the returned color string to remove the Alpha works. getResources().getString(R.color.my_colour).substring(3);

Comment: This is not working any more, error 'Expected resource of type String'

Comment: @CliveJefferies You can add `//noinspection ResourceType` just above your statement.

Comment: `getResources().getString(0+R.color.someColor);` works

Comment: @lordmegamax what do you mean by that? Adding that line is just a comment and has no effect.

Comment: @CACuzcatlan It's not just a comment, it's an annotation for lint. http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings

Comment: @scottyab `substring(3)` doesn't solve the problem since it also remove the `#` and you end up with `123456` instead of `#123456`.

Comment: @CliveJefferies is that you ??

Comment: Not useful having trouble of param type mismatch.

Comment: This will give error as, "Expected Resources of type String"
Use the below code for getting the hex value.
 ```String colorStr = "#" + Integer.toHexString (getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));```

Comment: Expected resource of type string less...
Ensures that resource id's passed to APIs are of the right type; for example, calling Resources.getColor(R.string.name) is wrong

Comment: Just add `@SuppressLint("ResourceType")` above the `getString` call like this:
`@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
        String someColorHex = resources.getString(R.color.a_color);`

Comment: @Tanmay Mandal Getting Expected resource of type string after using colorStr=getResources().getString(R.color.someColor);

Answer (score 161):

Just for the sake of easy copypasta:

```
"#" + Integer.toHexString(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.some_color));
```

Or if you want it without the transparency:

```
"#" + Integer.toHexString(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.some_color) & 0x00ffffff);
```

Comment: This worked great, however I needed to modify this by using `'#' + Integer.toHexString(getResources().getColor(R.color.someColor);` since later I was using it in `Color.parseColor`

Comment: geColor() need api > 23

Comment: You can use the deprecated getColor() no problem. Just delete the "getColor(...)" and type it out again, use intellisense to complete the method call with the Android deprecated getColor call and you're good.

Comment: Integer.toHexString(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black) & 0x00ffffff);

Comment: This won't work if there is 0 at first of the hex color.

Answer (score 49):

All of the solutions here using `Integer.toHexString()` break if you would have leading zeroes in your hex string. Colors like `#0affff` would result in `#affff`. Use this instead:

```
String.format("#%06x", ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.your_color) & 0xffffff)
```

or with alpha:

```
String.format("#%08x", ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.your_color) & 0xffffffff)
```

Comment: in Kotlin:
String.format("#%06x", ContextCompat.getColor(context, color) and 0xffffff)

Answer (score 27):

The answers provided above are not updated.

Please try this one

```
String colorHex = "#" + Integer.toHexString(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.dark_sky_blue) & 0x00ffffff);
```

Answer (score 10):

Cause `getResources().getColor` need api > 23. So this is better:
Just for the sake of easy copy & paste:

`Integer.toHexString( ContextCompat.getColor( getContext(), R.color.someColor ) );`

Or if you want it without the transparency:`

`Integer.toHexString( ContextCompat.getColor( getContext(), R.color.someColor ) & 0x00ffffff );`

Comment: `ContextCompat.getColor` does not take 3 arguments

Comment: @Nashe it is 2 arguments, not 3!

Answer (score 7):

It works for me!

```
String.format("#%06x", ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.my_color) & 0xffffff)
```

Answer (score 6):

For API above 21 you can use

```
getString(R.color.color_name);
```

This will return the color in a string format.
To convert that to a color in integer format (sometimes only integers are accepted) then:

```
Color.parseColor(getString(R.color.color_name));
```

The above expression returns the integer equivalent of the color defined in color.xml file

Answer (score 2):

Add @SuppressLint("ResourceType") if an error occurs. Like bellow.

```
private String formatUsernameAction(UserInfo userInfo, String action) {
        String username = userInfo.getUsername();
        @SuppressLint("ResourceType") String usernameColor = getContext().getResources().getString(R.color.background_button);
        return "<font color=\""+usernameColor+"\">" + username
                + "</font> <font color=\"#787f83\">" + action.toLowerCase() + "</font>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is standard functionality for that. You can however turn the return in value from `getColor()` to hex and turn the hex value to string.

hex 123456 = int 1193046;

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've done it:

```
String color = "#" + Integer.toHexString(ContextCompat.getColor
(getApplicationContext(), R.color.yourColor) & 0x00ffffff);
```