# android how to highlighted an text

Tags: android

I have created a listview. and there I also did the drag n drop of items.
I want on which item mouse touched that text should be highlighted.(For example U open the Google & if put the mouse on Google then it highlit the text Google in small letters) 
I wanna same on my list items TextView items.
How can I do it. Please answer me.
Thanks

Comment: @Jyosyna: when you clicked the List Items, you want to display tooltip , am i right????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're stuck on the highlighting text in a TextView part, here's an example of that, borrowing heavily from [Highlight Text in TextView or WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120035).

```
public class Main extends Activity
{
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
    myTextView.setText(myTextView.getText(), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    Spannable text = (Spannable)myTextView.getText();
    text.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    myTextView.setText(text);
  }
}
```

If instead, you just want to set the background color of the TextView, take a look at [android TextView: setting the background color dynamically doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466788).

Comment: Ya but it only for Text background. I want Tooltip.