# How to setBackground reflecting immediately in Android

Tags: android, events, onclick

I develop a quiz application in Android.
I want to show all question on single activity. When user selected a choice, if it is correct, set color is green, if it is false, set color red. And get new question and choices. I wrote code on onClick event:

```
public void onClickChoice(View v)  {
    String text = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();

    if (text == currentAnswer) {
        v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(newGreen));
    } else {
        v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(newRed));
    }

    setNewQuestion();
}
```

When run application, I answered first question and second question is came, and  color  of second question's choice is changed.
What should I do for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try with `setOnClickLisenter();` implemented in the class

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red); //or green, blue,...
```

Original answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466788/android-textview-setting-the-background-color-dynamically-doesnt-work)

Comment: @MHilmiKoca From what I understood, you want to see the background changes. Well, if you change it and then you skip to another question, of course the second background is green/red when you are in the background of the other question. So you have to wait. Where's the problem? Can you explain yourself better?

Comment: I don't see new color (green/red) on first question. Immediately(or 3 second later) second question come with red/green color.
My expectation is   I answer first question and choice's color is change. And get second question with default color. I answer second question and its choice's color is change. Etc

Comment: @MHilmiKoca oh so forget the previous code. Use v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);

Answer (score 0):

Is this in a list or recycler view?

if so, each view is recycled, so you'll need to specifically set the background colour on each view as it initiates.

Comment: I use a list for questions

Comment: can you at your Adapter.getView() and i'll see if i can help.

Comment: I use minSdkVersion is 14. Can I do with that