# customizing Image in a Fragment

Tags: android, image, android-fragments, android-image

I'm trying to make my image circular(**NOTE**: not trying to make ImageView circular but the Image) and fill it with a background color.
my fragment  code:

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_profile, container, false);
    ImageView mView = (ImageView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.dp);
    RoundedBitmapDrawable im = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getActivity().getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.my_image));
    im.setCircular(true);
    im.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER);
    mView.setImageDrawable(im);
    return rootview;
}
```

all I get is a non-circular image with no background color on running the app.

**EDIT**:I achieved the results using

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

But I still want to know why the first code did not work.

**EDIT :**
I also tried `im.setCornerRadius(Math.max(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight()) / 2.0f);` but to no avail

**EDIT 2:**
I was using Glide(and I really feel stupid for leaving out this information from the question) to display images from firebase storage and it turns out that images from glide are not bit-drawable  but transition-drawable and thats why the code did not work

Comment: You should set im.setCornerRadius()

Comment: nope did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Glide(and I really feel stupid for leaving out this information from the question) to display images from firebase storage and it turns out that images from glide are not bit-drawable but transition-drawable and thats why the code did not work

Answer (score 1):

You can use drawable to make your `ImageView` circular. Create new xml file in drawable folder.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/myColor">
    </solid>

</shape>
```

And implement your color in `color.xml`

```
<color name="myColor">#ffffff</color>
```

Finally set background to your `ImageView`
Hope it helps.

Comment: Then you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11376610/7482319) answer. This may allow you to manage your drawable file.

Comment: for setting bacground color dynamically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466788/android-textview-setting-the-background-color-dynamically-doesnt-work 
might be useful.