# Add background color to TextView in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to add a background color to two TextViews in Android studio, one is supposed to be red, and the other one is supposed to be blue. I currently have it set to random.

```
public void buildGuiByCode( Activity activity, int width, int height,
                                int numberOfPieces ) 
{
        positions = new int[numberOfPieces];
        tvs = new TextView[numberOfPieces];
        colors = new int[tvs.length];
        params = new LayoutParams[tvs.length];
        Random random = new Random( );
        labelHeight = height ;
        labelwidth = width / numberOfPieces;

        for( int i = 0; i < tvs.length; i++ ) {
            tvs[i] = new TextView( activity );
            tvs[i].setGravity( Gravity.CENTER);
            colors[i] = Color.rgb( random.nextInt(255 ),
                    random.nextInt(255 ),   random.nextInt(255 ) );
            tvs[i].setBackgroundColor( colors[i] );
            params[i] = new LayoutParams( labelwidth, height );
            params[i].topMargin = 0;


            params[i].leftMargin = labelwidth * i;
            addView( tvs[i], params[i] );
        }
    }
```

Comment: is it background color or text color ?

Comment: background color

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android TextView: setting the background color dynamically doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466788/android-textview-setting-the-background-color-dynamically-doesnt-work)

Comment: @CharlieBatista Just for record accept solution which you think helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setBackgroundResource` for setting up the background color. Here is a snippet.

```
TextView textView = new TextView(activity);
textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
```

Refer to this official [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int))

Comment: You need to click on the right symbol to accept the answer

Comment: @CharlieBatista you might like this post https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work